# vb.net InvalidOperatorException when using GetType() method inside XMLSerializer

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, typeof, gettype

I'm working on a program that reads from an online xml file, loads it into an interface, converts the xml file into a structure and loads the stuctures into a random access file, then reads the data from the random access file into a json file. I'm currently getting an InvalidOperationException when I try to serialize the file. Part of the code is below:

```
Private Sub cmdReadXML_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdReadXML.Click
'Read XML from xmlURL, Display in InventoryGV, Write to a Random Access File in the Data directory.'

Dim xmlFile As XmlReader
xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(xmlURL)
Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)
InventoryGV.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

Dim fileName As String = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory).FullName).FullName + "\Data\raf.xml"
FileOpen(1, fileName, OpenMode.Random, FileShare.ReadWrite)
FileClose(1)
Dim stream As FileStream = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)

Dim Serializer As New Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(Inventory))

Serializer.Serialize(stream, xmlFile)

End Sub
```

The last line `Serializer.Serialize(stream, xmlFile)` throws a System.InvalidOperationException with the message {"There was an error generating the XML document."}. The inner exception reads {"Specified cast is not valid."}.

If I look at the runtime value of GetType(Inventory) of the previous line `Dim Serializer As New Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(Inventory))`, I see a DeclaringMethod error: "DeclaringMethod = 'DirectCast((GetType(Inventory)), System.RuntimeType).DeclaringMethod' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'"

My best guess is the GetType() method is returning a runtime value, while the serializer needs to know the value at compile time. If so, is there a function to return the type value at compile time? The TypeOf function only seems to work for Boolean expressions, and I'm not sure of another function in vb.net that would do this.

If this isn't the case, where am I going wrong, and how can I successfully go about this? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the Inventory structure as well:

```
<Serializable()> Public Structure Inventory
    'Create Structure for Putting Inventory into Random Access File
    Dim id As Integer
    Dim year As Integer
    Dim make As String
    Dim model As String
    Dim terrain As String
    Dim mileage As Integer
    Dim color As String
    Dim cylinders As Integer
    Dim transmission As String
End Structure
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick glance at your line -`Dim Serializer As New Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(Inventory))`

I did not see a reference to Inventory, should this not be InventoryGV in order to make a call to file Inventory?

Might be wrong though...

Comment: I just added the code for the Inventory structure. InventoryGV is a DataGridView (that's what GV stands for). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Try to add this to your structure to see if any other reference errors appear, might be more descriptive - AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf UnhandledExceptionEventRaised. I have also noticed that you use "year" as an integer, try it as date or change the naming as year is a system used denominator.

Comment: Another note, not sure if you did, turn Option Strict On or put Option Strict On at the top of your code.